# sklearn's permutation_importance returns surprising result

Tags: regression, variance, feature-selection, scikit-learn, importance

I have simulated normally distributed data (`x_1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=1000)`) and used it to create a dependent variable with a linear combination of the data with equal coefficients (`y = 0.1 * x_1 + 0.1 * x_2 + 0.1 * x_3 + 0.1 * x_4 + 0.1 * x_5` ). Then I fitted a `LinearRegression` model. As all coefficients are equal, the models `coef_` returns as expected the correct coefficients `[0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1]`, but `sklearn`'s `permutation_importance` returns results that make it look like there are significant differences between the importance of the variables.

[image]

I used `ttest_ind` from `scipy.stats` to test for significant between the importances and many of them are significant, for example `x_1`and `x_4` have `Ttest_indResult(statistic=-19.330077252566138, pvalue=1.8116298872424227e-47)`.

How is this possible, given that the distribution of the independent variables and the coefficients in the linear relationship of the dependent variables are equal?

Comment: How many repetitions did you perform? By default it says 5.

Comment: Do you mean `n_repeats` in `permutation_importances`? I set it to `100`.

Comment: I would try increasing this, 1000 to be sure. Anyway, are all the x variables 1 to 5 created equal? Same mean and SD? If they are not that could explain the difference, for ex. if some variable is more/less variable than another that could impact predictive performance in the end.

Comment: Yes all variables are created equally like in the question with N(0, 1). Increasing `n_repeats` to 1000 doesn't change my observation -the results are even more significant. I'm also observing similar results with `eli5`'s `PermutationImportance`,

Comment: Might be worth checking on the variances of the `x_` variables - my guess is that, to the extent they differ as realized, they will affect permutation importance and produce the pattern here.  Their population variances are all 1, but 1,000 is not a huge sample and could result in relatively big deviations for each variable as realized in the sample.

Answer (score 4):

Permutation importance as implemented by Scikit for a linear model is based on the variance explained $R^2$ which is affected by both the coefficients and the variance of the variable underlying them.

For uncorrelated variables like these, the $R^2$ it will be (e.g., see this [article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313007x188252)):

$$R^2 = \beta_{x_1}^2\sigma^2_{x_1} + \beta_{x_2}^2\sigma^2_{x_2} + \beta_{x_3}^2\sigma^2_{x_3} + \beta_{x_4}^2\sigma^2_{x_4} + \beta_{x_5}^2\sigma^2_{x_5}$$

Thus, the $R^2$ depends on the variance of each variable in addition to the coefficient.

As you noted, the coefficient is recovered correctly by the model (all .1's), but the variances of the variables are not 1.  I've got a reproduction of what it looks like the OP did below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

rng = np.random.default_rng(100)

x_1 = rng.normal(0, 1, size=1000)
x_2 = rng.normal(0, 1, size=1000)
x_3 = rng.normal(0, 1, size=1000)
x_4 = rng.normal(0, 1, size=1000)
x_5 = rng.normal(0, 1, size=1000)

y = 0.1 * x_1 + 0.1 * x_2 + 0.1 * x_3 + 0.1 * x_4 + 0.1 * x_5

X = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5]).transpose())

mod = reg.fit(X, y)

r = permutation_importance(mod, X, y, n_repeats=30, random_state=0)
```

When I ask for the variances of the $x$ variables I get:

```
>>> X.var()
0    1.018847
1    0.929372
2    1.012899
3    0.973964
4    1.012116
dtype: float64
```

As can be seen, they vary from 1 and, in fact, vary along with the permutation importance results consistent with the $R^2$ computation.

```
>>> r.importances_mean
array([0.40259983, 0.37115351, 0.40572882, 0.38760295, 0.40320626])
```

With higher variances obtaining higher values.  I also get a similar result from a t-test:

```
>>> ttest_ind(r.importances[1], r.importances[2])
Ttest_indResult(statistic=-11.619849119793923, pvalue=8.908095916608572e-17)
```

Which, as I hope you can see, reflects the differences between the variances and not the differences between the coefficients (which I also get as all .1's; see below)

```
>>> mod.coef_
array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
```

Using more observations when generating the $x$ values and/or adding some prediction error into the $y$ equation should help make this effect less pronounced.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm surprised to see that the variance makes such a big difference for the permutation importance. I'm working in a project about variable importance and wanted to use permutation importance to rank variables. With the results of this small experiment it seems like testing for differences with the permutation importance is not possible, what do you think?

Comment: Testing for differences in importances could still be informative, but its just worth keeping in mind that they represent a combination of both regression coefficient as well as variance.  An alternative is, of course, to test for significant differences between the coefficients as it seems that may be more of interest and has a long history of application in statistics.